# centos6 lost '/etc/pki/tls/' folder

Tags: centos, ssl, directory

I am  trying to learn how to install `ssl_mod`, but with some wrong operation, I lost `/etc/pki/tls/` folder. I am trying to `yum remove mod_ssl`, `yum install mod_ssl`, but still can not create anything under `/etc/pki/tls/`. how to recover '/etc/pki/tls/' folder with all the default files? thanks.

Comment: My C6 box says that directory is owned and populated by the packages `ca-certificates-2010.63-3.el6_1.5.noarch` and `openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64`.  You won't be able to remove the latter, not without erasing the entire system, but there's a way I can't immediately remember that gets a package to reinstall itself cleanly (might be `yum reinstall ...`.  I thought it might be useful to you to know the packages you'll be wanting to do that to, if you can work out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got centos 6.4

```
[root@main ~]# cat /etc/centos-release 
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

Let's see which packages provide files and if there are any extra files:

```
[root@main ~]# rpm -q --whatprovides `find /etc/pki/tls/`|sort|uniq
ca-certificates-2010.63-3.el6_1.5.noarch
openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64
```

No, only these two.

Are any of these files changed? Verify:

```
[root@main ~]# rpm -V ca-certificates openssl
[root@main ~]#
```

No, now it's safe to download these packages:

```
[root@main ~]# yumdownloader openssl.x86_64 ca-certificates
Loaded plugins: versionlock
openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64.rpm                                                        | 1.4 MB     00:01     
ca-certificates-2010.63-3.el6_1.5.noarch.rpm                                               | 531 kB     00:00
```

OK, now let's see if there are any extra scripts in these packages to run manually:

```
[root@main ~]# rpm -qp --scripts ca-certificates-2010.63-3.el6_1.5.noarch.rpm
[root@main ~]# rpm -qp --scripts openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64.rpm
postinstall program: /sbin/ldconfig
postuninstall program: /sbin/ldconfig
```

No, so, it's enough to install them forcibly:

```
[root@main ~]# rpm -Uvh --force ca-certificates-2010.63-3.el6_1.5.noarch.rpm openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:ca-certificates        ########################################### [ 50%]
   2:openssl                ########################################### [100%]
```

You can run `yum reinstall openssl ca-certificates` too.

That's it.

Comment: hi, @GioMac, `CentOS release 6.2 (Final)` 
`-bash: yumdownloader: command not found`

Comment: `
Setting up Install Process
 No package yumdownloader available.`

Comment: `yum install yum-utils`

Comment: yum-utils success, but still `No package yumdownloader available.`

Comment: `yum-utils` provides `yumdownloader`

Comment: You can run `yum reinstall ca-certificates openssl` too.